# Remove the default url from anchor tag

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I have the following code which inputs a **link** from user and create an `anchor` tag with `href = link`

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
        #text-input {
            border-left: 4px solid green;
            text-indent: 12px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Enter a link</p>
    <div id="text-input" contenteditable="true"></div>
    
    <script>
      let div = document.getElementById('text-input');
      let anchor;

      div.addEventListener('blur', event => {
        let text = div.innerText;
        div.innerText = '';
        anchor = document.createElement('a');
        div.appendChild(anchor);
        anchor.innerText = text;
        anchor.href = text;
        
        // The below line logs the actual link of the anchor tag
        console.log(anchor.href);
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### PROBLEM

When I assign href the value of link, it appears that the link contains some default website url too. I don't want those default urls. What should I do?

Comment: *"link contains some default website url"*, can you please elaborate more?

Comment: @Arvind Try to enter any website link, and then you will see some default url before your entered link in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's a matter of relative urls? Add "http://" at the beginning of the text if the text doesn't have it.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your default requirement you can append https or http to the input data.

```
 anchor.innerText = text;       
            if(text.indexOf('http://')!=0 || text.indexOf('https://')!=0){
                text = "http://"+text;  //default http(or) https
            }
             anchor.href = text;
```

Answer (score 1):

you may need to add either http:// or https:// on the beginning.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style>
        #text-input {
            border-left: 4px solid green;
            text-indent: 12px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Enter a link</p>
    <div id="text-input" contenteditable="true"></div>
    
    <script>
      let div = document.getElementById('text-input');
      let anchor;

      div.addEventListener('blur', event => {
        let text = div.innerText;
        div.innerText = '';
        anchor = document.createElement('a');
        div.appendChild(anchor);
        anchor.innerText = text;
        anchor.href = 'http://'+text;
        
        // The below line logs the actual link of the anchor tag
        console.log(anchor.href);
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```